# Show Data in tree inside primefaces picklist

Tags: primefaces

I want to show data in tree structure inside `primeFaces` `pickList`. Below is the code:

XHTML:

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities}" itemValue="#{cities}" > </p:pickList>
```

This code shows all the data present in a city and shows it normally. When I put tree inside `pickList` it does not show it in tree format.

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities}" itemValue="#{cities}" >

<p:tree value="#{countryBean.root}" var="node">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

</p:pickList>
```

Comment: XHTML:

<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities}" itemValue="#{cities}" >
</p:pickList>

This code shows all the data present in city and shows normally. When i put tree inside picklist it doesnot show in tree format.


<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{countryBean.cities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities}" itemValue="#{cities}" >

<p:tree value="#{countryBean.root}" var="node">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

</p:pickList>